# Centos6 PHP7 Install SPL_Types

Tags: centos6, php-7, pecl

I am running CentOS 6 and am trying to install the SPL_Types extension for PHP7. I have php7 up and running however, any time I do pecl install SPL_Types,
I get massive compiler errors and can't find a way around. Ubuntu users can fix the issue by installing libpcre3-dev, but this is not a valid package on CentOS 6. I have verified that pcre and pcre-devel are installed and the latest version. Does anyone have a solution to this?

EDIT 1: A full log when I run the sudo pecl install SPL_Types command: http://pastebin.com/QG3mFjaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it figured out. For those who wish to know, I had to use a third party source to compile and install the extension, then I had to edit my php.ini file manually to add the new module.

https://github.com/esminis/php_pecl_spl_types

then once you have it, run the commands:

```
phpize --clean
phpize

chmod +x configure

./configure --prefix=/usr
make install
```

Then, edit your php.ini file and under the dynamic modules section, add

```
extension=spl_types.so
```

Restart the httpd service by doing

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Then verify the new module is loaded with `phpinfo()`.